# Extracting value from an headerless array located inside a variable, Laravel eloquent query result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I do not know wheather it is a silly question or newer for you too. I am getting a search result in forms of an array in one complicated laravel eloquent query, which is stored in say **"post"**.

When I am echoing this with

```
{{ $post }}
```

it is simply giving result like this

```
{"id":10,"post":"first","about":"first1","user_id":4,"likes":0,"points":2,"dcoms_count":0,"views":307,"created_at":"2013-11-01 19:52:41","updated_at":"2013-11-06 13:07:37"}
```

But I am unable to extract one single data  from this table. like when I run

```
{{ $post->id }}
```

it is giving error output. can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access it like an object, this should be the correct way:

```
{{ $post['id'] }}
```